# how to compile package with debug option

Tags: cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is newbie cmake question or rosbuild question, but is there way to compile package with debugging option as -g, -pg? (I found  make VERBOSE=1 can generate more verbose output message, so look for something like make DEBUG=1 option.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35218/how-to-compile-package-with-debug-option/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your `CMakeLists.txt` define this near the top:

```
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2015-08-26**:
This does not work for catkin

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-01-13**:
True, but note that the question was originally asked with the rosbuild tag, and answered in 2012.

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2016-01-21**:
Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS_BUILD_TYPE option above appears to be incorrect for catkin. The proper build command is:
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

---

Originally posted by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) with karma: 300 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2015-08-26**:
This is the correct answer. But this compiles all packages in the workspace with debug flags. Is there a way to target just one?

**Comment by [JulesW](https://answers.ros.org/users/27347/julesw/) on 2016-06-30**:
with -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="your_package_name,other_package_name" or with -DCATKIN_BLACKLIST_PACKAGES= ...